# How to run a python file that's inside a jar?

Tags: java, python, jar, zip

```
public class Bar {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        String pythonPath = this.getClass().getResource("data/__hello__.py").getPath();

        String command = new StringBuilder()
                        .append("python ").append(pythonPath)
                        .append(" -v ").append("201309")
                        .toString();
        CmdLineUtil.runFromCommandLine(command);
    }
}
```

When I run Bar without the JAR file, it works fine. 
The command I end up executing is

`python ~/projectDirectory/com/__hello.py -v 201309`

However, when I create a jar file from my project : `test.jar`

```
$jar tf test.jar
com/__hello__.py
com/Bar.java
```

and try to execute it:

`java -classpath test.jar com.Bar`

I get this error

```
ERROR - "python: can't open file 'file: ~/projectDirectory/test.jar!/com/__hello__.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory\n"
```

Anyone know how I can fix this problem? Do I have to unzip the file from the jar and make the command point to the unzipped file? I'd like to avoid doing this if possible.

Comment: I think you're going to have extract the file first to the local disk and ran that

Comment: Or you could write the content of the file onto the standard output, and pipe that into Python (with `python -` (`echo 'print "foo"' | python -` will output `foo`), see http://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html)

Comment: @Alex how would I pass in the arguments -v 201309 as well?

Comment: I assume you could pass it directly yourself into `sys.argv`. A little hack like this before writing the content of your Python file: `echo "import sys;sys.argv = ['-v', '201309'];print sys.argv" | python -`

Comment: @MadProgrammer Python has a zipimporter - it can directly import from zip files. But I do not know if it can execute from there.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers, I chose to just make a system call to unzip the files inside Bar